# Custom type in QVariant converts to empty string

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, types, qvariant

I'm writing a lexical scanner that generates a stream of tokens from some input. Those tokens have a *type* and a *value*. Since I'm using Qt I chose to store the token data as a `QVariant`. This works pretty well for token data that is of a non-custom type.

Unfortunately, I have several custom types that are stored inside of tokens as well. The tokens have a `toString()` function that outputs a token description (for debugging), but for all tokens that have data of a custom type this function gives an empty string. The code goes like this:

Test.h:

```
struct Test
{
    QString value_;

    Test(const QString& value = "");
    QString toString();
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Test)
```

Token.h:

```
struct Token
{
    TokenType type_;
    QVariant value_;
...
    virtual QString toString() const;
};
```

Token.cpp:

```
QString Token::toString() const
{
    QStringList sl;
    sl << "Token(" << ::toString(type_) << ", ";
    sl << value_.toString() << ")";
    return sl.join("");
}
```

Example output from scanner:

```
"Token(TT_TEST, )" 
"Token(TT_PLUS, +)" 
"Token(TT_NUMBER, 5)" 
"Token(TT_end, #)"
```

The `TT_TEST` token contains a Test class and I would expect the variant to print it's value. Unfortunately this does not work, and I've tried a lot of solutions that did not work. My current workaround looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool writeToStringList(QStringList& sl, QVariant v)
{
    if (!v.canConvert<T>()) return false;
    sl << v.value<T>().toString();
    return true;
}
```

and a modified `toString()` function:

```
sl << "Token(";
sl << ::toString(type_) << ", ";
if (!writeToStringList<Test>(sl, value_)) {
    sl << value_.toString();
}
```

and I have to do this for all my custom types which just feels pretty clumsy and wrong.

I figure there must be a better solution to this problem. Can anyone of you:

- Tell me how to solve the problem with the `QVariant` in a better way, or
- suggest a totally different solution without a `QVariant`. (I had a template solution earlier but I ran into different problems there, so I would need an example if that is suggested).

?

Comment: Where do you call `qRegisterMetatype`?

Comment: I don't, as the documentation [states](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType): "To use the type T in QVariant, using Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() is sufficient. To use the type T in queued signal and slot connections, qRegisterMetaType<T>() must be called before the first connection is established." [and](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType): "Warning: This function is useful only for registering an alias (typedef) for every other use case Q_DECLARE_METATYPE and qMetaTypeId() should be used instead." Currently I have no UI implemented (yet!).

Answer (score 5):

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() is in fact sufficient to enable aggregation of a custom type in a QVariant. This does not cover aspects like implicit type conversion and comparison in context of the QVariant though.
Qt5 assumed, to facilitate implicit conversion to QString you may do the following:

```
#include <QMetaType>

struct Token {
    QString _value;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( Token* );

QString tokenToString( Token* t ) {
   return t->_value );
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QMetaType::registerConverter<Token*,QString>( tokenToString );

    Token t = { QString("hello") };
    QVariant value;
    value.setValue( &t );
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

This is of course also possible (and more save) with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( MyType )` and directly aggregating a Token instance in the QVariant instead of a pointer to Token.

See also [this post from the Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/44751/qvariant-conversion-from-usertype-to-int)

Comment: I will try that out when i get back to this topic, which can be a longer time period, I'm currently not using Qt :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to register a QString converter to the meta-object system for the custom type Token

To do that, you have two ways:

1. Your custom type Token has already a method toString() (or equivalent)

Then you can directly register this method as converter

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <functional>

struct Token
{
  QString toString() const
  {
    return _value;
  }

  QString _value;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( Token )

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   qRegisterMetaType<Token>();

   QMetaType::registerConverter(&Token::toString);

   Token t {"hello"};

   QVariant value;
   value.setValue( t );
   qDebug() << value.toString();
}
```

2. The toString() function is external (not a method of the custom type Token)

Then you can register this external toString function using unary function

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <functional>

struct Token
{
 QString _value;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( Token )

QString tokenToString(const Token &t)
{
 return t._value;
}

struct toQString : public std::unary_function<Token,QString>
{
 QString operator() (const Token &value) const
 {
   return tokenToString(value);
 }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  qRegisterMetaType<Token>();
  QMetaType::registerConverter<Token, QString, toQString>(toQString());

  Token t {"hello"};

  QVariant value;
  value.setValue( t );
  qDebug() << value.toString();
}
```

PS: If you want to do

```
qDebug() << value;
```

you need to implement the QDebug operator in your custom Type,
and register this operator for the custom type Token to the meta-object system.

```
QMetaType::registerDebugStreamOperator<Token>()
```